# Как лучше оптимизировать код?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, как лучше сделать.
Есть экран LinearLayout, внутри него еще LinearLayout, и в нём TextView. По сути:

```
        <LinearLayout
             <LinearLayout
                TextView/>
             <LinearLayout
                TextView/>
        </LinearLayout>
        и тд.
```

С сервера приходят данные, и некоторым поля присваивается значение null, соответственно, отображать на экране не стоит, и нужно спрятать не сам TextView, а контейнер. Как сделать, чтобы не приходилось очень много кода вручную писать?

```
    Мой код 
    String type = types.getType();
    Long value = values.getValues();
    AQuery aq = new AQuery(rootView);//библиотека чтобы кода меньше было

      aq.id(R.id.tv_type).text(type); // это вместо findViewById и setText
                    type!= null ? type: "");

    И теперь, инициализируем контейнер
    ll_type       = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ll_type);
    if (type==null) ll_type.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Одно поле отобразили.
```

Comment: можно у требуемых textView брать getParent(), и парент прятать

Comment: Не очень понятно, но предположу, что можно динамически добавлять элементы в соответствии с ответом сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таких случаях неплохой вариант динамически добавлять элементы в зависимости от данных, которые приехали с сервера.
Например, у нас есть некий `ArrayList<Template> templates`, содержащий произвольное количество объектов с данными, и есть mainLayout, куда надо добавить ваши LinearLayout с TextView.
Тогда в активити можно сделать так:

```
int listSize = templatesList.size();
LayoutInflater vi = getLayoutInflater();
for (int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i) {
    final Template template = templates.get(i);
    final View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    mainLayout.addView(view);
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    tvTitle.setText(template.getTitle());
}
```

Сам же файл R.layout.item - это отдельный xml файл, содержащий ваш LinearLayout с TextView.
Это если данные однотипные. Если же нет, то надо смотреть уже на сами данные, каким образом можно развести их по типам.